# javascript changing .text font color

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to change the font color of individual .texts in JavaScript? Depending on a user input 1 of a few options could happen and I would like to change the color depending on the selection. Note CSS can change the color for the `<td>` but not change depending on a selection.

```
var latedifference = 0;
    latedifference += late-lates
     if (late > lates && latedifference <= 2){
        $('#lateedge').text('Your Team has the Edge');
    }else if (late > lates && latedifference > 2){
        $('#lateedge').text('Your Team has a Big Edge');   
    }else if (lates > late && latedifference < -2){
        $('#lateedge').text('Opposing Team has a Big Edge');   
    }else if (lates === late){
        $('#lateedge').text('Teams are Even');
    }else {
        $('#lateedge').text('Opposing Team has the Edge');
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can change the font color of individual text with js.

Comment: What is `lateedge`, a `<td>`?

Comment: yes it is <td>, initially it was line items but I wanted to data to go from left to right as oppose to top to bottom and it was just getting too confusing on my website to line it up horizontally so I just made a table instead.

Answer (score 1):

After `.text('Your message')` add `.css('color', '<your color>')`

Comment: Thank you so much I tried something similar to that but I guess the syntax was off, you are a lifesaver and timesaver!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font color in the same statement where you change the text, either by changing it directly or changing a css class:

```
if (late > lates && latedifference <= 2){
    $('#lateedge').text('Your Team has the Edge');
    $('#lateedge').css('color', 'blue');
}else if (late > lates && latedifference > 2){
    $('#lateedge').text('Your Team has a Big Edge');  
    $('#lateedge').css('color', 'green')

    // or, if you have css to go with it
    // like .big-edge { color: green; }

   $('#lateedge').toggleClass('big-edge')
[etc.]
```

Another thing - it's bad for performance to keep querying `$('#lateedge')` over and over; instead, cache it at the beginning so jQuery only has to look for that selector once.

```
var latedifference = 0;
var $td = $('#lateedge');

...
$td.text('Teams are Even')
```

Comment: ID selectors are extremely fast and jQuery does some internal caching -- there's likely no difference in performance in this case, especially since only one if-block should be running. Although it *is* good practice, and it certainly looks cleaner and is more maintainable. +1 from me!

Comment: wow I am very new to jquery and javascript and only started doing it out of necessity for a friend of mines site but that is a great piece of information and greatly appreciated.